# How to save onclick count into mysql table using php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a download link when the user click the download link the counter should be stored in database table via ajax using php. i have tried with the following code . Is this the right way to store or we need to increment the count in php file.

```
$('#doc_attachment').click(function(){

                    init_count++;       
                    $.ajax({
                        url:'<?php echo $block->getUrl("orderattachments/customer/doccount") ?>',
                        type:'POST',
                        data:"&initial_count="+init_count+'&',
                        dataType:'json',
                        success:function(response){
                            console.log("tse");
                        },
                        error:function(request, status, error){
                            console.log(request.responseText);

                        }       

                        })

                    })

            error:function(request, status, error){
                        console.log(request.responseText);

                    }       

                    })

                })
```

Comment: From my point of view you should increase it with php means at backend because on frontend everytime the browser is refreshed that init_count will start from 0. or you can retrieve it from database and then increment it

Comment: the counter should be incremented in the PHP-file otherwise every user of the page could just change the value. You should alway use the approach: Do not trust data that comes from the client.

Comment: That `init_count` variable looks like a global one … so what would possibly happen if I just typed `init_count = -999` into my browser console, and then clicked your button afterwards …? If it was not global, it would not be that easy to manipulate, but still possible of course, for example in the debugger. And that same request you are making here could be made outside of your script, even outside of anything that you would call a “browser” …

Answer (score 0):

Hope `doccount` is a `PHP` function to update the count. If so, you can try below query:

```
UPDATE countertable 
SET counter = counter + 1 
WHERE counterid = <ID_related_to_downloading_doc>
```